# Code explanation - object-oriented programming

Tags: c#

Please look at this code:

```
 public class User
 {
     public string username = String.Empty;
 }

 static void Main(string[] args)
 {
     int counter = 10;
     User john = new User();
     User paul = new User();

     Execute(counter, john, ref paul);

     Debug.WriteLine(counter);
     Debug.WriteLine(john == null ? "null" : john.username);
     Debug.WriteLine(paul == null ? "null" : paul.username);
 }

 public static void Execute(int ctr, User John, ref User Paul)
 {
     ctr++;
     John.username = "John";
     John = null;
     Paul.username = "Paul";
     Paul = null;
 }
```

Pay attention that the "Execute"'s third parameter is passed via reference.
The program will output:

```
10 
John
null
```

So, I understand the following:

- "10" value and
- null in the third row

But why the object John still have username "John" even it got the NULL? (object destroyed)

Comment: You did answer yourself: _"Pay attention that the "Execute"'s third parameter is passed via reference."_. [That's the reason](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14akc2c7.aspx).

Comment: A class is a reference type, that is the question.

Comment: `null` is in no way object destroyed! It's 'reference released', but to fully understand what that means you'll need to learn more about reference types in C#

Comment: I understand why the Paul is NULL. My question is about the second one. John got his username and then is destroyed, still why he existing in the static Main ?

Comment: Answering this question would entail explaining the entire concept of reference types in C#. This is too broad a subject to fit in a typical answer. Please read more about the subject and when you have a better grasp of it you can ask more specific questions that can be answered in a more concise manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> John got his username and then is destroyed, still why he existing in the static Main ?

Because `User john = new User()` does two things:

1. Create an instance of type `User` and
2. Store a reference to that variable in `john`.

If you then execute `john = null`, the reference (2) becomes `null`, but the object (1) still exists (until garbage collected).

Reference types are by default passed by value, as you can read in [Passing Reference-Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s6938f28.aspx).

This means that in `Execute(User john)` you have a **copy of the reference to** `User john` initialized in `Main()`. If you set that copy to `null`, the original reference still exists, and so does the variable.

Calling `Execute(ref User paul)` will pass **the reference** initialized in `Main()` **by reference**. If you set that to `null` in that method, you're also nulling the reference in `Main()`.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Execute John holds a reference to the User object you created in Main (User john). When you set John to null in Execute John holds no longer a reference to the object created in main but instead null. 
**Without ref** you will get a reference to the object that you pass into the function
**With ref** you will get (simplified) the original paul variable inside Execute

In the case without ref you could see John as a pointer which holds the reference to the memory area where the actual object is stored. If you put null in the pointer you don't change the actual object but the content of the pointer. In the other case with ref you get the actual original variable from main and therefore if you assign null to it the original object gets replaced.

Answer (score 1):

Classes in .NET are reference types. In particular, this means, that when you define method parameter like this:

```
User John
```

you pass a *reference* to an object. I.e., `John` is a reference to a memory location, which is occupied by an instance of type `User`.

Any changes, made with `John` will modify object, that is referenced by `John` parameter, but you can't change memory location, which is referenced by this parameter.

On the other hand, this:

```
ref User Paul
```

declares *reference to a reference* to an object. The major difference is that you can change the object, that is referenced by `Paul`, and, **also**, change memory location (or, simple, address in memory), which is referenced by `Paul` variable.

Term "change" here means "affects to caller". Inside the method you can easily modify memory location for `John` parameter, but caller won't see this modification.

Assigning of `null` doesn't destroy an object instance. Note, that we're in managed environment - only GC decides, whether to release memory, or not. By assigning of `null` you just define, can you still access the object with any variable or you can't.

Comment: Thanks for a valuable answer!

Answer (score 0):

Objects in C# are always passed by reference - there is no such thing as passing an entire copy of the object. Even the original variable john is really just a reference to the object.

Therefore when Execute() updates John, it updates the original (only) copy of John. Hence "John" is printed in the second line of output.

When Execute() nulls John, it is only nulling its local reference to John. The variable john in Main() remains in tact.

With Paul, you have passed a Reference to a Reference - a reference to the variable john in Main, which is itself a reference to the actual User object.

When Execute() nulls that reference, it is nulling the original reference in Main, so the object is released from memory.

Comment: Sorry, slip of the pen - of course it's C#. But the answer stands.

Comment: Thanks for the valuable and descriptive answer!

Comment: @Sven44 actually objects **in C# are passed by value** (that's why we need ref to pass them by reference)...